# parsing a JSON document without childnodes returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

A webservice returns this JSON below

```
[
  {
"companyuserId": "2",
"name": "mike jones",
"superiorname": null,
"departmentId": "26",
"departmentname": "Design",
"companyId": "06",
"UDID": "8df912053a16ab2b4c66a",
"isActive": "1",
"devicetoken": "e8a4c1fad76b45d918f6745bfe60d32a81504",
"email": "mike@yahoo.co.uk",
"phone": "5456465465654"
  }
 ]
```

Thought it would be straight forward

```
            name = data.name;
            phone = data.phone;
            email = data.email;
            departmentname = data.departmentname;
            companyId = data.companyId;
```

But I'm getting undefined, How else can I do this? I think maybe the data maybe in string format because when I alert data I get the result as pasted above rather than object: Object

Comment: The outer square brackets are the issue.  The server is returning an array of objects, not just one object. (Well there's just one object in the array, but it's an array nevertheless.)

Comment: *"I think maybe the data maybe in string format..."*. If it's JSON, and it hasn't been parsed, then it *is* in string format. You need to parse it first. `var parsed = JSON.parse(data);` Then as the answers state, you need to access Array indices before you get to object properties. `alert(parsed[0].name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an `array of Objects`..  And the Object is the `First item` inside an array.. So you need to use the **index** to access the object inside it..

So instead of `name = data.name;`   try this `name = data[0].name;`

```
            name = data[0].name;
            phone = data[0].phone;
            email = data[0].email;
            departmentname = data[0].departmentname;
            companyId = data[0].companyId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object is an array of objects, so it has to be accessed with fully qualified name.

Try this:

```
name = data[0].name;
phone = data[0].phone;
email = data[0].email;
departmentname = data[0].departmentname;
companyId = data[0].companyId;
```